# Content alignt to bottom of page instead of bottom of div

Tags: css

I want my navigation text to be displayed at the bottom right of the header div but no matter what I try it only wants to align at the bottom of the page or some other position I do not want. I don't understand why this is happening, absolute should refer to the header div, correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    scroll: overflow;
}

.header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  height: 60px;
}

.header-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.left {
  background: #e8edf0;
  flex-basis: 45%;
}

.right {
  background: grey;
  flex-basis: 55%;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-navigation">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `position: relative;` to header. This will make the `.header-navigation` consider position from `.header` when you make it absolute.

```
 .header {
    position: relative;
 }

 .header-navigation {
    position: absolute;
 }
```

Now `.header-navigation` will use position according to `.header`

Answer (score 0):

> absolute should refer to the header div, correct?

Only if header div itself has a position.

When you set the position of one of its children to absolute as you have in this case, the system hunts back up the page to find the first ancestor element that has a position and then it positions the element you are trying to position relative to that.